# Consult array data in REST API Filter

Tags: filters, rest-api, json, plugin-json-api

Is it possible to make a filter with REST API Filter or any other technology to discover all elements that have job_listing_category = 86? Since job_listing_category is an array.

***Actual state:***
https://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing?filter[meta_key]=_case27_listing_type&filter[meta_value]=place

```
"job_listing_category": [
      132,
      86
],
```

Answer (score 0):

https://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing?job_listing_category=86

Simple solution, worked for me. I believe I'm sleepy.